# Image with 2 color channels?

Tags: python, keras

I have a dataset with over 12,000 images and while evaluating some of them visually they have an image shape which looks normal as I would expect with 3 color channels RGB

```
['10371.jpg']
 image shape: (375, 500, 3)
 array([[[128, 129, 134],
        [129, 130, 134],
        [130, 131, 135],
        ...,
        [209, 214, 218],
        [209, 214, 218],
        [209, 214, 218]],

       [[125, 126, 130],
        [126, 127, 131],
        [127, 128, 132],
        ...,
        [209, 214, 218],
        [209, 214, 218],
        [209, 214, 218]],

       [[123, 124, 128],
        [123, 124, 128],
        [124, 125, 129],
        ...,
        [206, 213, 219],
        [206, 213, 219],
        [206, 213, 219]],

       ...,

       [[196, 196, 196],
        [196, 196, 196],
        [196, 196, 196],
        ...,
        [ 81,  76,  70],
        [ 87,  82,  76],
        [ 88,  83,  77]],

       [[196, 196, 196],
        [196, 196, 196],
        [196, 196, 196],
        ...,
        [ 95,  90,  84],
        [106, 101,  95],
        [106, 101,  95]],

       [[196, 196, 196],
        [196, 196, 196],
        [196, 196, 196],
        ...,
        [ 99,  94,  88],
        [111, 106, 100],
        [109, 104,  98]]], dtype=uint8)
```

But then when trying to run through a model I get the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Rescaling, Activation
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def baseline_model():
  model = Sequential([
  Rescaling(1.0/255.0),                    
  Conv2D(filters=10,
         kernel_size=3,
         strides=1,
         input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
  Activation(activation='relu'),
  MaxPool2D(),
  Conv2D(filters=10,
         kernel_size=3,
         strides=1),
  Activation(activation='relu'),
  MaxPool2D(),
  Conv2D(filters=10,
         kernel_size=3,
         strides=1),
  Activation(activation='relu'),
  MaxPool2D(),
  Flatten(),
  Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')                                         
  ])
  return model

baseline_model_0 = baseline_model()

baseline_model_0.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                         optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                         metrics=['accuracy'])


history_0_baseline = baseline_model_0.fit(train_data,
                                          epochs=5,
                                          validation_data=test_data,
                                          steps_per_epoch=len(train_data),
                                          validation_steps=int(0.15 * len(test_data)),  # Evaluate on 15% of the testing data
                                          callbacks=create_tensorboard_callback(dir_name=tensorboard_dir_name,
                                                                                experiment_name='baseline_model_0'))

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Number of channels inherent in the image must be 1, 3 or 4, was 2
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1885]
```

How might I go about finding the image/images that are presenting the issue?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  I think we need to know how you "run through a model " to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Find images with `shape=(A,B,2)` maybe?

Comment: Added the rest of the code. The error is coming from `fit()`

Answer (score 0):

I am aware I am late to answer this but I figured that your dataset may have files that aren't jpeg. I run a script to make sure that my dataset only has jpeg/jpg format files as other formats can cause bugs to my model.I encountered this and resolve this yesterday.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35316444)